# junit test for my product controller on spring

Tags: java, spring

I have an activity than i need an CRUD(create, read, update, delete) operations on Java, and I'd used Spring Framework to build a RESTful Api. But right now i'm getting a few problems with UUID id, my generated value.

```
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import com.example.demo.dtos.ProductRecordDTO;
import com.example.demo.models.ProductModel;
import com.example.demo.repositories.ProductRepository;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn;

@RestController
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    @PostMapping("/products")
    public ResponseEntity<ProductModel> saveProduct(@RequestBody @Valid ProductRecordDTO productRecordDto) {
        var productModel = new ProductModel();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(productRecordDto, productModel);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(productRepository.save(productModel));
    }

    @GetMapping("/products")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ProductModel>> getAllProducts(){
        List<ProductModel> productsList = productRepository.findAll();
        if (!productsList.isEmpty()){
            for (ProductModel product : productsList){
                UUID id = product.getIdProduct();
                product.add(linkTo(methodOn(ProductController.class).getOneProduct(id)).withSelfRel());
            }
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(productsList);
    }

    @GetMapping("/products/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getOneProduct(@PathVariable(value = "id")UUID id){
        Optional<ProductModel> productD = productRepository.findById(id);
        if(productD.isEmpty()){
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Product Not Found");
        }
        productD.get().add(linkTo(methodOn(ProductController.class).getAllProducts()).withRel("ProductsList"));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(productD.get());
    }

    @PutMapping("/products/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> updateProduct(@PathVariable(value = "id") UUID id,
                                                @RequestBody @Valid ProductRecordDTO productRecordDTO
                                                ){
        Optional<ProductModel> productD = productRepository.findById(id);
        if (productD.isEmpty()){
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Product Not Found");
        }
        var productModel = productD.get();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(productRecordDTO, productModel);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(productRepository.save(productModel));
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/products/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> deleteProduct(@PathVariable(value = "id") UUID id){
        Optional<ProductModel> productD = productRepository.findById(id);
        if (productD.isEmpty()){
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Product Not Found");
        }
        productRepository.delete(productD.get());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Product was deleted sucefull");
    }

}
```

This is my ProductController code. How can I implement JUnit tests for each one of these functions?

Comment: i think you should create integration tests in this case, for more details i recommend to have look at this simple guide [testing-web](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/).